# Get HTML From Another File Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a collection of buttons and when I click them I am trying to display the HTML from a different file. I tried dabbling in JQuery but I decided I want to try doing it with fetch

Comment: Did you get content of file in front-end

Comment: from where are you reading the content of html file

Comment: check if you get content in response.

Comment: maybe try: `fetch('content.php').then(res => res.text()).then(response =>
     content.innerHTML = response);`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using jquery, you can try to use [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) method:

```
$(content).load('content.php');
```

---

Or if you still want to use `fetch` method:

```
fetch('content.php')
    .then(function(response) {
        var html = response.text();

        var parser = new DOMParser();

        var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");

        content.innerHTML = doc.innerHTML;
    });
```

Comment: The question is tagged and asked as javascript.

Comment: @Marissa Updated!

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to do it using `fetch()`.

```js
fetch('content.php').then(res => {
  if (response.status !== 200) {
    console.log(`Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ${response.status}`);
    return
  }

  res.text().then(text => {
    content.innerHTML = text
  })
})
```